# Android Styles and Themes xml - @style/ necesssary?

Tags: android, xml, themes

For example, I can set a style `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` or `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` Both seem working.

Isn't `@style/` necessary? On what cases they are necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's necessary, but better use `parent=Theme.AppCompat` , because it inherits from Material and gives you backwards compatibility.

Comment: If it's necessary, why removing "@android:style/" doesn't make any difference? It is still working without it.

Comment: That's strange, parent="Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I think "android:" is necessary. But for Theme.Appcompat.Light, both "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" and "Theme.AppCompat.Light" work. Then what does "@style/" do? Isn't it necessary? I guess "android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar" would work too?

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light` is directly defined in `values.xml` of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0` library, which you added as dependency. Try Ctrl+Left Mouse Button click on `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Hope it's now clear for you :)

Comment: Yeah, but why is it working with "@style/" and without? What does "@style/" do?

Comment: `@style/` is reference to `styles.xml` resource. You are able to put parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" when you are in `styles.xml` because it's part of this resource. You don't see it in `styles.xml` file, but it's linked to it. Making parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" it's like telling "go to styles and pick Theme.AppCompat.Light".

Comment: You can compare it to `private` variable. You can access this variable from the class which you declarated this variable, but you cannot access to this variable from other class. You need to do it using reference, and this reference is `@style/` in our situation.

Comment: You can check it by yourself by simply creating ex. EditText and adding as attribute `style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge"` - on preview you will see that look changed for this EditText. But if you instead add `style="Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge" you will see the same as without `style` attribute, because XML can't reach it (it doesn't know that it's in `styles.xml`.